# Storing computed values in database when reads are far higher than writes

Tags: c#, sql, json, database-design, sql-server-2012

I find myself faced with a conundrum of which the answer probably falls outside of my expertise.  I'm hoping someone can help.

I have an optimised and efficient query for fetching table (and linked) data, the actual contents of which are unimportant.  However upon each read that data then needs to be processed to present the data in JSON format.  As we're talking typical examples where a few hundred rows could have a few hundred-thousand associated rows this takes time.  With multi-threading and a powerful CPU (i7 3960X) this processing is around 400ms - 800ms at 100% CPU.  It's not a lot I know but why process it each time in the first place?

In this particular example, although everything I've ever read points to not doing so (as I understood it) I'm considering storing the computed JSON in a VARCHAR(MAX) column for fast reading.

Why? Well the data is read 100 times or more for every single write (change), it seems to me that given those numbers it would be far better to stored the JSON for optimised retrieval and re-compute and update it on the odd occasion the associations are changed - adding perhaps 10 to 20 ms to the time taken to write changes, but improving the reads by some large factor.

Your opinions on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: your're slowly inventing a NoSql database,  like mongoDB :)

Comment: have you consider cache ?

Comment: @Keith I had considered storing the calculated values in Mongo! :-)

Comment: @Mzf, yes I have.  Not sure if it's wise in this scenario, we're talking hundreds if not thousands of reads and maybe a dozen writes each day, problem is on each read the absolute latest is always required.  Not sure if with this in mind I would gain much?

Comment: you can update the cache on each write and always read from cache. this is common in cache

Comment: @Mzf, I'll have to look into that then.  My limited knowledge of caching meant that I thought it had to be read, I didn't realise you could update the cache upon read - silly really as it should be obvious!  Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: Another possibility: create a PERSISTED computed column (that is computed by a CLR function in your case).

Comment: Interesting alternative, thank you @BrankoDimitrijevic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, storing redundant information for performance reasons is pretty common. The first step is to measure the overhead - and it sounds like you've done that already (although I would also ask: what json serializer are you using? have you tried others?)

But fundamentally, yes *that's ok*, when the situation warrants it. To give an example: stackoverflow has a similar scenario - the markdown you type is relatively expensive to process into html. We *could* do that on every read, but we have *insanely* more reads than writes, so we cook the markdown at *write*, and store the html **as well as** the source markdown - then it is just a simple "data in, data out" exercise for most of the "show" code.

It would be *unusual* for this to be a common problem with json, though, since json serialization is a bit simpler and lots of meta-programming optimization is performed by most serializers. Hence my suggestion to try a different serializer before going this route.

Note also that the rendered json may need more network bandwidth that the original source data in TDS - so your data transfer between the db server and the application server may increase; another thing to consider.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for such a detailed response. I've not tried all of the serializers but I have tried a few, Newtonsoft's won hands down (using the manual write) due to the size of the response rather than a simple JsonConvert.Serialise(object) call. Thanks for the check on the server data-transfer, I'll run more tests but a couple of tests still generated a faster response with the storage, I just wasn't sure if it was the right thing to do.  In this case, you've helped sway me to storing it.  Thank you.